# runAction function will scale also children of a sprite, but not fade them

Tags: animation, sprite, cocos2d-js

I create a menu out of sprites and add a label to each sprite.

```
var items = [],
for( var i=0 ; i<players.length ; i++ ) {

    var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame("listviewitem"),
    spritesNormal = cc.Sprite.create(frame,cc.rect(0,0,380,100)),
    spritesSelected =cc.Sprite.create(frame,cc.rect(0,0,380,100)),
    spritesDisabled =cc.Sprite.create(frame,cc.rect(0,0,380,100));

    var label = cc.LabelBMFont.create( players[i].name , "res/fonts/bees50.fnt" , cc.LabelAutomaticWidth, cc.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER, cc.p(0, 0) );               
    spritesNormal.addChild(label, 5);   

    var listviewSprite = new cc.MenuItemSprite(spritesNormal, spritesSelected, spritesDisabled, this.onListviewTap, { self: this, player: players[i] });       
    items.push(listviewSprite);
}

this._listview = new cc.Menu(items);    
this.addChild(this._listview,1);
```

Later I try to animate one sprite of the menu list by:

```
var sprite = this._listview.children[i],

sprite.runAction(
    cc.EaseSineIn.create(
        cc.spawn(
            cc.scaleTo(1,3,3),
            cc.fadeOut(1)
        )
    )
);
```

But this fades out only the sprite but not the label. The scaling animation is done for the label also, just the fading not. What is the problem? Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually set `setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true);` on all children that you wish are recursively affected ([answer got from the forums](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/runaction-function-will-scale-also-children-of-a-sprite-but-not-fade-them/20781/2)).

If your sprite's children have chidlren (and so on), you'd need something more recursive, like:

```
var setCascadeOpacityEnabledRecursively= function(node, state){
  node.children.forEach(function(child){
    setCascadeOpacityEnabledRecursively(child, state);
  });

  node.setCascadeOpacityEnabled(state);
};
```

And then call it:

```
var sprite = this._listview.children[i];

setCascadeOpacityEnabledRecursively(sprite , true);

sprite.runAction(
  cc.easeSineIn(
    cc.spawn(
      cc.scaleTo(1,3,3),
      cc.fadeOut(1)
    )
  )
);
```